# How do you make images transparent when you hover them with your mouse?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, transparent

I'm new to programming with html/css and I'm trying to code a website for my class. Essentially, I'm trying to make the photos of this page: www.stanford.edu/~tayoamos turn more transparent and show another image on top when you hover them.

Here's my html and css for both:

HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title> Instalert </title>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="photos">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/cf16c8b4865411e3ab4012f602fa8bc2_8.jpg" alt ="JB1">
        <img src ="http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/68042be2857511e382bb121b6297674b_8.jpg" alt="JB2">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/9a5b791283bb11e3b33312c4f3a07952_8.jpg" alt "JB3">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/230ce59a831a11e38fdc120c7c565106_8.jpg" alt "JB4">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/70d891a6853211e3828f1225728e27b1_8.jpg" alt ="KK1">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/4462c49a853011e385020e36ca40396c_8.jpg" alt "KK2">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/80531368852811e39c3c12a357c94c82_8.jpg" alt "KK3">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/97b2d28484bd11e3a7630e29514d93ff_8.jpg" alt "KK4">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/e66c6606856c11e399cf1225396dfdfd_8.jpg" alt "RR1">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/ceaedd12849211e3928a0e05f3709127_8.jpg" alt "RR2">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/37805c6e83e211e3a1ab0af82f025223_8.jpg" alt "RR3">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/dcda744c83d811e3bbfc122878962eb0_8.jpg" alt "RR4">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;

}
#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }

#photos img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0,3s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0,3s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0,3s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0,3s ease;
          transition: all 0,3s ease;
}

 #photos:hover {
  opacity:.5;
 }



 }

}
```

Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: If you want so show another `img` you will need to use `javascript` `jQuery`.

Comment: @user3240333 : user participation is generally a good sign, telling if answers are helping or not!! :)

Comment: Interesting...it works after I take out the first parts of the css code. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

do it this way:

```
img:hover{
  opacity:0.4; /* how much transparent you want image to be*/
  filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* browser fix*/
  -webkit-opacity:0.4; /*vendor prefixes for website browsers*/
  -moz-opacity:0.4; /* same as above, edited thankx to @ Daniel_Lisik  */
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xWGAs/1/)

Also, your `alt` misses `=` in some `img` tags!

**EDIT**

To show images underneath when hovered on top image, you have to do following :

- `wrap` the pair of image which you want to show by default and on hover in a single `div`
- make the images `absolute` position and container `relative`.

**CSS**

```
.imgdiv, #photos {
    position:relative; /* very important */
}

/* stack images one behind other */
.imgdiv > img.top {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}
.imgdiv > img.bottom {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9;
}

/* this part css will work on hover */
.imgdiv > img.top:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.1; /* make top image go invisisble  */
    filter:alpha(opacity=10);
    -webkit-opacity:0.;
    -moz-opacity:0.1;
}
```

[**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xWGAs/2/)

Comment: don't forget `-webkit-opacity:0.4; -moz-opacity:0.4;` for cross-browser support.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps tremendously. Do you know how I would add another image on top of it? Like when you hover over it the image is more transparent but then another image comes on top of it?

Comment: Also I put in the code and it still doesn't work...maybe it has something to do with the "#photos" syntax or something?

Comment: @user3240333 : added an edit answer...please check!!

Comment: @user3240333 : glad i could help....will you mark the answer as accepted so that question can be considered closed?? :)

Answer (score 0):

Opacity property does not work for ie8 and use filter:alpha(opacity=40)to make the image transparent

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not my area of expertise, I've found couple resources you might want to check out (in case you already haven't):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

http://themes.themaxdavis.com/tutorial/transparent_images

Both of these contain some easy-to-understand examples.

Comment: its always great to post an answer with an example + links for further informations. http://www.w3fools.com here we go ;)

Answer (score 0):

Opacity with css transition effect

http://jsfiddle.net/ByBtt/

```
img {
-webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
-moz-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
-ms-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
-o-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}

img:hover{
opacity: 0.5; 
-webkit-opacity: 0.5;
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```